# Silverlight application running on FF gets CommunicationException during accessing a web using WCF through SSL, but not IE nor Chrome

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis-7.5

I know this exception is pretty popular for SL and WCF developers since I saw tons of posts asking solutions, but I can't find a similar question to my situation, so could anyone help me?

I have a SL app which uses the WCF accessing an IIS 7 through SSL. Basically it works well, but when I run it on FireFox3.6.6, it gives me the CommunicationException when calls the IIS 7, but not IE8 nor Chrome5.

I really don't have ideas why only FF doesn't work.

Here is my environment,
Silverlight 4
.Net framework 4.0
Visual Studio 2010
IIS 7
SSL

If you need any source codes or config snippets, please let me know.

Thanks in advance, 
yokyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. I'm using a self signed certificate which is created by IIS 7 for test purpose. And FF doesn't allow users to trust it without settings. So, to use the self signed certificate on the FF,

go to Options -> 
Settings (At the very right something looks like 'Gear' icon) -> 
Encryption tab -> 
Display certificates button -> 
Add an exception button -> 
Type your url and get your certificate

The above explanation might be different from your FF, since I'm using it in Japanese. So please imagine what I want to say ;)

Cheers,
yokyo